# How much faster is the Z80H?

Tags: z80, performance

The Z80A, rated for a maximum clock speed of 4 MHz, was a very widely used CPU in the 8-bit era.

The Z80H, introduced in 1986, was rated for a maximum clock speed of 8 MHz. This would at first glance appear to provide an excellent drop-in upgrade in cases where a computer is trying to be backward compatible with an older model, but now has fast enough memory chips to support the higher speed; you would get exactly double speed, which can easily be halved again for old hardware or software that depends on exact timing.

However, InfoWorld Oct 18, 1982, says, "Performance gained from the Z80H is expected to exceed that of the standard 4-MHz Z80 by four to six times. The new version of the Z80 has been designed to take advantage of 16-bit peripherals originally intended for Zilog's contender in the 16-bit race, the Z8000."

That seems to imply that it also decreases the number of clock cycles needed to carry out typical instructions. Is that the case? If it is, that would be good news for the extra performance, but bad news if you also need the ability to run at exactly the old timing; no way to have both abilities in the same chip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Z80H is, to my knowledge, an exact drop-in replacement for the original Z80, just with a higher clock frequency. The instruction set and the pin-out (if purchased in the same package) are 100% identical.

InfoWorld's comment would rather point into the direction that the new CPU would be able to keep up with the speed of the mentioned devices - just because of its higher clock speed. I don't see why the citation would seem to "imply a decreased number of clock cycles".

The very same [article](https://books.google.de/books?id=CjAEAAAAMBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=InfoWorld%20Oct%2018,%201982&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVt-nHm7LYAhUR5qQKHWs7B1Q4PBDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=Z80H&f=false) states that the improvement (to get the CPU to work at 8 MHz) was achieved by improving *the process control* rather than *the mask*  in production which clearly tells me that thing is identical to a Z80A.

Comment: I'd guess it's *confused by marketing blurb* - It escapes me why doubling the clock frequency could more than double performance (maybe in constructed cases involving I/O, where you would, for example, have to wait for another revolution of a disk because you missed a sector, but definitely not in raw computing power)

Comment: Read carefully. The articles says 'performance **gained from** the Z80H', not 'performance **of** the Z80H'. Disk interleave is one obvious example where doubling the I/O speed could result in much faster _system_ performance, particularly for a disk-bound OS such as CP/M.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Still marketing blurb - A 4 to 6 times improvement could only be achieved if you transform a badly designed I/O system based on a Z80A  into an optimized system based on a Z80H.

Comment: http://www.retrotechnology.com/herbs_stuff/drive.html#interleave

Comment: @BruceAbbott I think that's what I'm saying - But adapting sector skewing to the I/O system's performance doesn't cost *anything* (except re-formatting a few disks). And it doesn't involve a new CPU.

Comment: @tofro: In some applications where fixed-rate background processes use up the majority of CPU time, doubling the CPU speed may significantly more than double the rate at which the CPU can process foreground tasks.  If background tasks would normally use 3000 out of 4000 cycles every millisecond at 4MHz, leaving 1000 available for foreground tasks, increasing the CPU to 8MHz so those tasks take 3000 out of 8000 cycles every millisecond could offer a five-fold speed boost.  Not a terribly common scenario, but it can happen.

Comment: @supercat Your calculation is somewhat misleading: It results in a five-fold speed-boost *of the foreground application* - Your background tasks run exacly at the same speed as before. For them it's a 1-fold speed boost (i.e. nothing). This is a bit like calculating the mileage of a car on downward slopes only, in my opinion.

Comment: @tofro: In many systems, there is a fixed amount of work that must be done by background tasks every second.  In embedded systems where those tasks represent a system's primary job, and in cases where faster systems would cost more, it would not be uncommon for those fixed-load background tasks to use most CPU time.

Comment: @supercat I know all this - still your calculation seems to be like cheating to me. If you can speed up 25% of a system by five times, that is not "a five-fold speed boost" to me